# How am I supposed to use two C structs for one queue or stack?

Tags: c, struct, stack, queue, structure

I was given the following struct definitions for an assignment revolving around queues and stacks:

```
struct entry
{
            bool operation;
            char op;
            int num;
};

struct node
{
            bool operation;
            char op;
            int num;
            entry * next;
};
```

The assignment is easy enough, but I'm not sure how to implement these structures into a queue or a stack. I thought that if you wanted to create a linked list, then, you used only one structure. Is there any way to use this setup? Could it be a typo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something is off. Your node can point to a "next" element but this "next" element can't point to anything else.

I suspect it should actually look like this:

```
struct entry {
    bool operation;
    char op;
    int num;
};

struct node {
    struct entry *entry;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: See, that's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure because my teacher can be rather incomprehensible... I was wondering if I was missing something. Thank you, seriously!